# .dockerignore not ignoring any files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My `.dockerignore` file isn't doing anything, and I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong.

I have `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml` and `.dockerignore` all within the root of the project.

`.yml`:

```
version: "3.5"
services:

  gateway:
    build: .
    ...
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine

EXPOSE 10091

WORKDIR /root
COPY . .
```

`.dockerignore`:

```
.ash_history
.env.*
.git
.gitignore
.idea
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
client
```

I have tried specifying a single file in case my formatting is bad, but it still didn't do anything. I have also tried deleting the image and creating it again (even though I am using a `docker-compose up -d --build` each time).

I suppose that `COPY` action from the `Dockerfile` executes after the ignoring of files takes place?

Comment: what's your OS?

Comment: MacOS Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: is it work with `docker build ...`?

Comment: How are you verifying the .dockerignore file doesn't work? Please show your steps in a way that can be reproduced. See [mcve]

Comment: I SSH to it and see they are still there.

Comment: Do you mean docker exec or SSH? And SSH to where?

Comment: Docker exec yeah